# Primes with a twist

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, source-layout

Note: this is heavily inspired by *[this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92944/hyperprogramming-nn-n%C3%97n-nn-all-in-one)*.

## Task:

Your task is to generate the `n`th prime, when each character of your program is repeated `n` times in place.

Let's say your program is:

```
Derp
```

Every character in there is repeated once, so it should output `2`.

When every character is duplicated in place, like so:

```
DDeerrpp
```

This should generate the 2nd prime, which is `3`.

## Specs:

- Your program must accept no input, and output the respective prime.
- Your program must work for all primes, given enough time and memory.
- Leading and trailing newlines are fine.
- The output must be in the default base of the language - if there is no default, any base is fine.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Does *Your program must work for all primes, given enough time and memory.* mean I cannot use, e.g, int in C?

Answer (score 22):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ŀo‘’FQỌµḟ;¹V
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcxL9v4oCY4oCZRlHhu4zCteG4nzvCuVY&input=) or [run the first ten programs](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=eMOQ4oKsMTBW4oKsRw&input=&args=4oCcxL9v4oCY4oCZRlHhu4zCteG4nzvCuVY).

#### Background

Jelly has several different types of string literals; all of them start with a `“`. If the literal contains more than one `“`, a string array is returned, and `“` separates the strings from each other.

For example, `“abc“def”` yields `['abc', 'def']`.

Depending on the last character of the literal (any of `”«»‘’`, where `«` is currently unimplemented), one can choose between the different types of literals. For `‘`, we get the code points in [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) instead of the corresponding Unicode characters.

For example, `“abc“def‘` yields `[[97, 98, 99], [100, 101, 102]]`.

The literals in the first three programs correspond to the following code point arrays.

```
“Ŀo‘           -> [199, 111]
““ĿĿoo‘        -> [[], [199, 199, 111, 111]]
“““ĿĿĿooo‘     -> [[], [], [199, 199, 199, 111, 111, 111]]
```

#### How it works (**n = 3**)

```
“““ĿĿĿooo‘‘‘’’’FFFQQQỌỌỌµµµḟḟḟ;;;¹¹¹VVV  Main link. Implicit argument: 0

“““ĿĿĿooo‘                               Yield the 2D array
                                         [[], [], [199, 199, 199, 111, 111, 111]].
          ‘‘                             Increment twice, yielding
                                         [[], [], [201, 201, 201, 113, 113, 113]].
            ’’’                          Decrement thrice, yielding
                                         [[], [], [198, 198, 198, 110, 110, 110]].
               F                         Flatten, yielding
                                         [198, 198, 198, 110, 110, 110].
                FF                       Twice more. Does nothing.
                  Q                      Unique; yield [198, 110].
                   QQ                    Twice more. Does nothing.
                     Ọ                   Unordinal; convert the Unicode code points
                                         198 and 110 to 'Æ' and 'n'.
                      ỌỌ                 Twice more. Does nothing.
                        µµµ              Begin three monadic chains, all with
                                         argument s := "Æn".
                           ḟ             Filter-false; remove the characters of s
                                         from s, yielding "".
                            ḟḟ           Twice more. Does nothing.
                              ;;;¹       Concatenate with s three times, yielding
                                         "ÆnÆnÆn".
                                  ¹¹     Identity function. Does nothing.
                                    V    Eval the resulting Jelly code, i.e.,
                                         call the next-prime atom thrice, with
                                         initial implicit argument 0.
                                     VV  Eval two more times. This is a no-op
                                         on integers.
```

Comment: This definitely is in need of an explanation... and depending on how it's laid out, it might be the only language that can do this?

Comment: What... how? That is simply way too quick.

Comment: @ValueInk I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 22):

## GS2 ([commit 67fea47](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/tree/67fea4776db4af37c3df830ca4793c1ee1e9ddc8)), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
dnR
```

#### How it works

Like most commands, GS2‘s `d` is overloaded. Initially, there's an empty list (the input or the lack thereof) on the stack, so `d` computes its sum. After the first iteration, there's a **0** on the stack, and `d` computes its parity (also **0**). Thus, no matter how many times we repeat `d`, the result will always be a single **0**.

The next part is straightforward. The command `n` pops the top of the stack and pushes the next prime number. Thus, repeating `n` **k** times computes the **k** prime.

Finally, the command simply applies *str* to the top of the stack, which converts a number to its string representation and does no affect strings. Thus, no matter how many times we repeat `R`, the result will be the string representation of the **k** prime.

Comment: what on earth!?

Comment: Do Not Resuscitate